# wysiwyg widget not working in custom plugin module

Tags: menu, widgets, wysiwyg, plugin

In our Magento webshop, we have a custom plugin that was build by our template builder that we bought on themeforest a vew months ago. There is no support anymore on this template, so if something is wrong with the template of plugins, we have to figure it out ourselfs.

A week ago, we created two additional store views for two additional languages. These are working now. But the problem is that a certain widget in the wysiwyg of this plugin is not working anymore.

The template is from Cooncook, and it has a custom megamenu plugin build in.

When I go to the megamenu item and I select one to edit, it gives me a wysiwyg editor to edit the contents of the menu dropdown div.
[image: wysiwyg editor]
And there are a few widgets that we put in the content.
The problem is that when we want to edit the widgets, we get a 404 page.

[image: 404 message showing in widget window.]

The strange thing is that I can add widgets on static blocks or normal pages, but I get a 404 on this plugin page.

Can anybody give me a lead on where I can look for code or a trace on where to look for a fix?

I hope somebody can give me a clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself after a week of headache!..

Here it is:

When you want to edit the widget, you dubble click on it to open a popup, and change its values. The URL where the post request is made to was different. Because the url went to index.php/admin, but we've changed the magento admin url to 'beheershop'.

So probably the line /admin is hardcoded, otherwise it would have changed automatically.

Eventuelly the headache causing file is:
app/code/local/Templines/Themedesigner/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Form.php

Change the word: 'admin' to whatever you have changed your login url into, at line 22 and 27 in the str_replace function.

I this will help someone in the future.

In the CoonCook template ( the one we've purchased ).. there is a post